# SQL-optimization puzzle: Larger query + more joins = greater speed. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have an application which contains a module responsible for automated query-building. This module enables an ordinary user (not a programmer) to add extra "formulas" which are injected into queries. The module seemed to be not optimal, because it translated many simple formulas (for example retrieving different fields from the same "child" table) into a lot of joins. So, I decided to optimize it, so that it could combine similar formulas into a single join. But now I'm stuck, because I built a query which is almost two times smaller and has a smaller number of joins, but it runs four times slower than the non-optimized query. So, here they are:
**Non-optimized**:

```
SELECT f1.id FROM object_73130_ f1   
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73400_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field, CONCAT_WS(" ",o.attr_73201_,o.attr_73202_,o.attr_73203_) AS attr_73400_ FROM object_73200_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73200 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o414_1_0 ON f1.id = o414_1_0.id_field    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73206_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73206_  FROM object_73200_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73200 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o4_1_0 ON f1.id = o4_1_0.id_field  
LEFT OUTER JOIN object_73101_ t_4_1_0_0 ON t_4_1_0_0.id = o4_1_0.attr_73206_    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_81084_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_81084_  FROM object_73200_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73200 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o252_1_0 ON f1.id = o252_1_0.id_field   
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73199_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73199_  FROM object_73195_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73195 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o249_1_0 ON f1.id = o249_1_0.id_field    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73217_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73217_  FROM object_73195_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73195 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o250_1_0 ON f1.id = o250_1_0.id_field    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73197_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73197_  FROM object_73195_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73195 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o251_1_0 ON f1.id = o251_1_0.id_field    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT attr_82212_ ,id FROM object_69534_ f1 
ORDER BY  f1.id_order  
) AS o354_1_0 ON (f1.attr_73140_=o354_1_0.id)    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT attr_82212_ ,id FROM object_69534_ f1 
ORDER BY  f1.id_order  
) AS o356_1_0 ON (f1.attr_82225_=o356_1_0.id)    
INNER JOIN ( SELECT f1.id FROM object_73130_ f1   
WHERE f1.id_obj = 73130 ORDER BY  f1.id_order  DESC , id DESC LIMIT 0, 300 ) AS lim ON lim.id = f1.id
```

On my data set it runs for 0.6 seconds.

And here is its **optimized** version, which is four times slower (on the same data set):

```
SELECT f1.id FROM object_73130_ f1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73206_, attr_81084_ , attr_73400_   FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73206_, attr_81084_, CONCAT_WS(" ",o.attr_73201_,o.attr_73202_,o.attr_73203_) AS attr_73400_ FROM object_73200_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73200 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o4_1_0 ON f1.id = o4_1_0.id_field  
LEFT OUTER JOIN object_73101_ t_4_1_0_0 ON t_4_1_0_0.id = o4_1_0.attr_73206_       
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73217_, attr_73197_ , attr_73199_  
FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73217_, attr_73197_ , attr_73199_   
    FROM object_73195_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73195 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o250_1_0 ON f1.id = o250_1_0.id_field   
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT attr_82212_ ,id FROM object_69534_ f1
ORDER BY  f1.id_order  
) AS o354_1_0 ON (f1.attr_73140_=o354_1_0.id)    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT attr_82212_ ,id FROM object_69534_ f1 
ORDER BY  f1.id_order  
) AS o356_1_0 ON (f1.attr_82225_=o356_1_0.id)    
INNER JOIN ( SELECT f1.id FROM object_73130_ f1   WHERE f1.id_obj = 73130 ORDER BY  f1.id_order  DESC, id DESC LIMIT 0, 300 ) 
AS lim ON lim.id = f1.id
```

The queries by themselves may have no sense for you. But the fact is, the second optimized query is running much much slower. I tried to investigate the reason and found out that the second query became slower because of one field `attr_73197_` of type `VARCHAR(128)`. In the first `non-optimized` query this field translated into a single join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73197_ FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73197_  FROM object_73195_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73195 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
)  AS o251_1_0 ON f1.id = o251_1_0.id_field
```

In the optimized version this field injected into another join here:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73217_, attr_73197_ , attr_73199_  
FROM (
    SELECT m0.id_field,  attr_73217_, attr_73197_ , attr_73199_   
    FROM object_73195_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_object = 73130 AND m0.id_master = 73195 AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY  o.id_order 
) AS o  GROUP BY id_field 
 )  AS o250_1_0 ON f1.id = o250_1_0.id_field
```

But all this resulted in a very low speed. If I comment out this field, then the optimized version now starts to run quicker than its counterpart. So, how can it be?

**EDIT**

I now start to think that the problem may result from the field of type `TEXT`. Maybe MySQL makes some internal optimization, when this field comes alone, but does not do that, when it comes with other fields. I do not know.

**EDIT**
The result of the `EXPLAIN` command for the optimized query:

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys       key         key_len ref                 rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived8>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  300 
1   PRIMARY     f1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY             8           lim.id  1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  949 
1   PRIMARY     t_4_1_0_0   eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY     8       o4_1_0.attr_73206_  1       Using index
1   PRIMARY     <derived4>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  947 
1   PRIMARY     <derived6>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  13  
1   PRIMARY     <derived7>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  13  
8   DERIVED     f1          ALL     \N   \N     \N                  \N                          947                                 Using filesort
7   DERIVED     f1  ALL \N  \N      \N                  \N                                     13                                   Using filesort
6   DERIVED     f1  ALL \N  \N      \N                  \N                                     13                                   Using filesort
4   DERIVED     <derived5>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  947     Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DERIVED     m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N          \N      \N                  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DERIVED     o           eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY     8       project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
2   DERIVED     <derived3>  ALL     \N                  \N          \N      \N                  949 Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED     m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N          \N      \N                  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED     o           eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY     8       project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
```

**EDIT**
The result of the `EXPLAIN` command for the non-optimized query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived16> ALL \N  \N  \N  \N  300 
1   PRIMARY f1          eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   lim.id  1   
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  949 
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  949 
1   PRIMARY t_4_1_0_0   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   o4_1_0.attr_73206_       1  Using index
1   PRIMARY <derived6>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  949 
1   PRIMARY <derived8>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 
1   PRIMARY <derived10> ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 
1   PRIMARY <derived12> ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 
1   PRIMARY <derived14> ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  13  
1   PRIMARY <derived15> ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  13  
16  DERIVED f1          ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 Using filesort
15  DERIVED f1          ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  13  Using filesort
14  DERIVED f1          ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  13  Using filesort
12  DERIVED <derived13> ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 Using temporary; Using filesort
13  DERIVED m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N  \N  \N  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
13  DERIVED o           eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
10  DERIVED <derived11> ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 Using temporary; Using filesort
11  DERIVED m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N  \N  \N  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
11  DERIVED o           eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
8   DERIVED <derived9>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  947 Using temporary; Using filesort
9   DERIVED m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N  \N  \N  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
9   DERIVED o           eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
6   DERIVED <derived7>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  949 Using temporary; Using filesort
7   DERIVED m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N  \N  \N  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
7   DERIVED o           eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
4   DERIVED <derived5>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  949 Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DERIVED m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N  \N  \N  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DERIVED o           eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ALL     \N  \N  \N  \N  949 Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED m0          ALL     indx_master_slave   \N  \N  \N  2782    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED o           eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   project.m0.id_slave_field   1   Using where
```

**EDIT**
I don't see how `EXPLAIN` can explain my strange case. But my final verdict is that it is all because of the field of type `TEXT`. By some mysterious reason it goes well in a single `join`, but it causes a lot of trouble in a `join` with some other fields. But I would like to have a more rigorous explanation.

Comment: run explain on the query and post it.in general subqueries are slower than joins

Comment: What fields from the explain command are most informative to post?

Comment: post all of the fields